# Quote from one dealership, work done at another

Tags: toyota, differential, wheel-bearing, dealer, tundra

I'm on a cross-Canada trip from BC to Newfoundland. I noticed a problem which sounds like a wheel bearing going. I took it to a dealer in New Brunswick, and they claim the rear diff is bad (metal shavings in oil etc), so they quoted me a price for the work.

They assumed I wouldn't be getting the work done there, that I'd wait to get it done further on in the trip.

I'm a bit worried about how quick they were to write up a quote for the work ($5,000+). This is a 2018 Toyota Tundra with 119k on it. They obviously have all of my information, so my question is thus: If someone gets a quote for parts and labour at one Toyota dealership, will that dealership make commission on the parts/work even if I get the work done at a completely different one?

Comment: For that much money it's worth getting another quote, just for your piece of mind. Also, take it to a reputable independent mechanic, not a dealer, you'll save a lot of money and still get quality work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, no. If they don't do the work, they don't get paid. That's even if you take it to another Toyota dealership.